CSRF token mismatch error in response when submit a form in laravel 11 application
I am using Laravel 11 for build a application in which a admin panel i have created and created a front-end website. In front-end website a form is exist. when i submit a form than request is not called and HTTP status code 419 unknown status is coming. and when inspect the request in browser. the response is showing "CSRF Token mismatch"
Errors
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/itmbwv8j.png)
web.php
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Front\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Front\ComplainRegisterController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

// Admin Routes
Route::get('admin', [UserController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('admin/auth', [Usercontroller::class, 'auth'])->name('admin.auth');
//Route::middleware([AdminAuth::class])->group(function (){
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
//});



// Website page Routes
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/onlinecomplain', [ComplainRegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('onlineComplain');
Route::post('/registercomplain', [ComplainRegisterController::class, 'store']);

Form in Blade Template
<form action="{{url('/registercomplain')}}" method="POST" class="contact-form contact-form">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email">
                                    <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="captchafill" name="captchafill" placeholder="Enter Captcha" type="text">
                                    <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{-- <img src="{{ captcha_src() }}" id="captcha-img" class="captcha"> --}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send OTP
                                </button>
                                <!-- <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="d-none">Submit</button> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Alert Message -->
                        <div class="col-lg-12 alert-notification">
                            <div id="message" class="alert-msg"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ComplainRegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('front.onlinecomplain');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($request->post); die;
    }
}


how to resolve this issue. Please guide me
Thanks

Are you using ajax/javascript to submit the form?

Look in your html to see if the CSRF token is being generated. It looks as though because you are using an action in your form that there should not be any JS messing with it. However, could you confirm that and update your question with the html rendered. Your VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware file and Http/kernel.php. Lastly check the config/session.php to make sure that it is configured correctly.


Double-check that the @csrf directive is present in the form and is rendering correctly in the HTML output.
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/registercomplain') }}">
    @csrf
    <!-- rest of your form fields -->
</form>

Then, view the page source in your browser. You should see a hidden input field like this:
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="randomTokenStringHere">


Verify that the VerifyCsrfToken middleware is properly configured in the app/Http/Kernel.php file.

Checking VerifyCsrfToken middleware:
Open app/Http/Kernel.php and look for the web middleware group. It should
include \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,. If it's missing, add it.


Check the session configuration in config/session.php, especially the session driver and lifetime settings.
{
'driver' => 'file',
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'secure' => false,
}


Try clearing the application cache and regenerating the application key.
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear




I think you did not use csrf_token on the head section of your template. Use like this below.
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
on your head section of the template.

@csrf adds the csrf token to the form. It's not necessary to add it to the meta tag as well.

add this tag in your master blade inside head section
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>

After addign this run following command
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize:clear

